# Use of article 'the'

Tags: indefinite-article

Of Rama and Usha **the latter is the more** responsible.
I think use of *the* is superfluous before competative degree **more**.
But my book suggest that the given sentence is absolutely right. Please explain if there is any rule regarding this in English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence would be correct either with or without the inclusion of **the**.

When **the** is included, the sense is that Usha is **the** more responsible person; or **the** more responsible of the two.

When the **the** is omitted, **more** simply acts to modify **responsible**.

Another example might be:

> She is more capable.
> She is the more capable (**person** is implied)
> She is the more capable administrator.

Both constructions are correct. It depends on exactly what you want to say.

Comment: The expression **the more [adjective]** is used when explicitly comparing two people or things; it can be followed by **of the two**.